# preventDefault function: What is the real utility?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie in jquery and saw a piece of code with something strange given the functionality of a method, the "preventDefault". Well, to test, i created a test page and made two functions with "preventDefault" inside of it.

I have two questions on the same subject, i hope you can answer me.

```
$(document).ready( function( ) {
    $('a').click( function( event ) {//Func 1
        event.preventDefault( );
    });

    $("#ok").click( function( event ) {//Func 2
        event.preventDefault( );
        alert("Wut");
        //...
    });
});
```

1- Why, in the second function, the "alert( )" runs even if i comment "event.preventDefault( );" and the first function does not happen the same? If i comment "event.preventDefault();" in the first function, the link doesn't work!
I found it strange because regardless of the method "event.preventDefault();" whether or not commented in the second function, the "alert" works the same way. I think even what comes after "alert" would run.

2- What is the real utility of this method, "event.preventDefault ();"? Why, in the second function, it seems to be useless. Can you give me some example of when it might be useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) is to prevent the browser's default action related to the event. Your `alert` isn't the browser's default action, and is unaffected. Following a link **is** the browser's default action, and so preventing the default prevents following the link.

`preventDefault` is crucial in many situations. For instance, when handling a form's `submit` event, we need `preventDefault` (directly or indirectly) if we do client-side form validation and the form isn't valid; otherwise, the browser would submit the invalid form.

(I said "directly or indirectly" above because jQuery handles the return value of event handlers in a special way: If you return `false`, it calls `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` for you.)

Answer (score 1):

It prevents the *default action* of the control. If it a link, it stops the link being followed. If it is a form submission, it prevents the form from being submitted.

It doesn't interact with other JS event handlers on the same element.

Examples of situations where you might use it:

- Stopping the browser following a link because you have used Ajax and pushState to load the content and update the URL
- Stopping the browser from submitting a form because you have tested the data entered and found a problem with it

Answer (score 0):

The `.preventDefault()` function prevents the browser from carrying out the normal implicit behavior of an interactive element. If you click on an `<a>` tag, then apart from anything your JavaScript does the browser will attempt to follow the "href" value and reload the page. That's the "default" behavior that the function name refers to.

Your `alert()` runs because `.preventDefault()` has nothing to do with the code in your event handler. If you want to "abort" an event handler, you'd just `return` from it.

Note that jQuery also gives you `.stopPropagation()` and `.stopImmediatePropagation()` to cancel the process of event bubbling. Those also have no direct effect on the code in your event handler.

Comment: Wow this one trolled in quite a crowd :)

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` disables the default behaviour of the event. In case of an link the redirect. It does not effect your own code, in this case the alert() call.